# How to update password if current password is blank in devise gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise

I am doing authentication through facebook so the password field is updating as blank. So if i want to update the password as the current password is nil. Any solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the `user` in your `rails console` and simply update the password attributes like this:

```
u = User.find_by_email email
u.password = u.password_confirmation = "password"
u.save
```

Comment: current_user is not accessible in rails console. Please accept my answer if it helped you. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

[Read this document](http://blog.cloud-mes.com/2013/01/23/change-devise-user-password-in-rails-console/). This says you can simply pass password and comfirm password and save the user data. If still you find issue share your server log. so that we can have more solutions